# help identifying artist seals

Tags: character-identification, seal

I inherited a number of Chinese paintings from my grand-father who bought them in the south China seas in 1918-1919, and hope[image: flying birds] to find who the artists were from the seals.

Answer (score 2):

the seal is read as “陳涓”, most likely is the name of the artist.

i would suggest try to find info about “潮州” & “陳涓” of early 20th century.

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=陳](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%99%B3)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=涓](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%B6%93)

Comment: I think the top-right of the 涓 character in the image has some problems when compared to authentic seal script.

Comment: I am not an expert,  this site provides a good starting point about the 涓 character in the image [link] (http://zidian.shufaai.com/shufazi/juan_2098_1.html)

Comment: @dROOOze, the top right component is “expressed” as a stand-alone “口”, imo  http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=口